# how to reduce .apk mmap size in my android app

Tags: android, webview

When i never open activity with webview, I dump my app meminfo,is like:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p012V.png)

When i open an activity with webview, I dump my app meminfo,is like:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPyrU.png)
When i close this activity,the .apk mmap (Pss Total and Private Clean)is still very large. I have add and remove webview dynamically and called webview.ondestroy() when activity is destroyed. Why .apk mmap remains unchanged? What the .apk mmap means? Anyone can help me, Thanks!

Comment: an idea on how to reduce?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/android-platform/c/YlyV1YxvNXg , this is the same question asked by you and you solved it by putting your webview activity in another process. Apparently for me I am not using webview , but would want to know how to reduce .apk mmap.

Comment: @miracle-doh, you can refer this, https://groups.google.com/g/android-platform/c/YlyV1YxvNXg

Comment: @NoobAndroidDeveloper that's exactly what I did.. thanks!